Who do I call to prevent frozen pipe reoccurrence?
Last winter, one toilet in the basement stopped filling. This was during a prolonged spell (uncommon here) where the temp (in Fahrenheit) was down in the teens. I discovered that the only affected fixture was the toilet. The sink and shower in the same bathroom worked, both hot and cold. All other fixtures in the house worked. The only things I don't remember checking were two outside hose bibs. The valve is on an outside wall, but I don't know where any other piping is.  (It's a finished basement.)
The problem resolved itself as the temp rose. There doesn't appear to be any pipe breakage.
I'd like to prevent this from happening again, but I'm not quite sure the best way to pursue. I do not plan on doing any of the work myself.

Who should I call to address this?
How likely are they to want to tear into the walls? Are there methods of tracing pipes without tearing out all the drywall along the path?
If just the one basement toilet stopped working, is it reasonable to assume that it was the last thing in that particular stretch of piping?

Thanks for any help you can provide in helping me determine the best people to help me prevent this from happening again.

Is the toilet closer to the hose bibs?

Thermal camera will usually show the path of a cold (or hot) water pipe behind drywall if you let the water run for a while.

They may trace the pipes without needing to damage the wall, BUT you should expect them to need to open the wall to add insulation to protect the pipe.
Just consider that "planned damage" to open a wall is limited in area and a LOT cheaper than the consequences of a burst pipe that you may not find instantly.

Agree with this info.  But also keep in mind that insulation by itself just slows down temperature changes.  It doesn't stop things from freezing, just slows it down.  So just putting insulation around a water line that doesn't have water movement (or other source of heat to counteract the cold) very often will still freeze - it will just take longer.

If the inside of the house is heated and you insulate the pipe from the cold outside, then insulation can very much prevent freezing of pipes.

Recommended to keep the bathroom door open when not in use to allow warm air to circulate

A person familiar with the ways of plumbers can make a pretty good educated guess as to the route a pipe may take, at least for the few feet in which it is (presumably) exposed to cold by being installed in an exterior wall.
You mentioned this occurred in a basement. Basements, by definition, have little exposure to sub-freezing temperature by virtue of being below ground level. By chance does your water heater/furnace closet have a combustion air intake from outside? If it does (and it should, unless your fuel-burning appliances are fully electric or use sealed combustion) then does that air intake path happen to cross over/near this bathroom where the freezing occurred? If so there's a chance that the pipe serving the toilet could have frozen in the ceiling by crossing through that cold air inlet path. It may be possible to look into that path from indoors or outdoors to visually check for water pipes crossing it.
Given this freezing condition is uncommon where you are, you might consider simply letting a trickle of water run continuously until the freeze risk has passed. The fill valve or the flush flapper valve could be adjusted to let a trickle of water flow.
A generalist in the spectrum from handyman to general contractor could help you find the pipe and make a plan to add insulation that protects from outdoor cold and remove insulation that prevents enough indoor heat reaching the pipe. A plumber could look at the insulation situation too, but they also would have the ability to solve this by re-routing the pipe through a less freeze-prone path.

Many basements are not completely below ground, and it's not uncommon for the concrete exposed above ground to be completely uninsulated, resulting in something like an R0.5 wall exposed to the cold. If the basement is "finished" by insulating the inside and then the pipes are run next to the concrete, freezing is very likely.

Thanks for the replies.  I may go the flapper trickle route for now.
The basement is -- if I understand the term correctly -- a daylight basement.  Viewed from the front, the house appears to be one floor, but from the back, it's two floors.  The toilet valve in question is about midway between the front and back of the house, so I think it's quite possible that the pipe takes a path where it's at or above ground level right next to the concrete basement wall.
Is it possible to find the pipe without tearing out the wall? I understand they'd have to tear out some once the pipe is found.

@Rick There are inspection tools that could help. A borescope camera can give a view into a space with a smaller, more patchable hole. A device such as Walabot may or may not let you "see" the pipe through the drywall. Intuition goes a long way too - one who has done plumbing can make educated guesses as to how it might be routed.

+1 for re-routing. That is 100% what a plumber would do. Route the pipe where it is easy to get at. A new route with exposed pipes or bulky conduits can be unsightly, but nobody who has a concern about a pipe buried in their wall wants their decoration wrecked just to have the pipe put back in the wall again.
